# Bing Maps in a Listbox boundary issue

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Normally the silverlight controls know where they are in terms of who is in front of or behind. An example is putting an image inside a listbox and when you scroll up and down in the listbox, the image will disappear/hide inside the listbox boundaries.

I have put a bing map object(the one that comes with the windows phone 7 sdk) inside a listbox. When I scroll to where the map is in the listbox, it is acting like I have some flag set to "Always on Top". I can't seem to find a property that is setting this or if it's inherent in the way the maps are designed.

I haven't tried this yet, but I'm curious if I add layers with pushpins in them if they too would act "Always on Top". I've included an image to explain. As you can see below, the map is outside of the listbox's bounding area and is even overlapping a button outside of the listbox.

[Link to Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM0ms.png)

```
<ListBox Height="590">
<TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="#F80046" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Map"></TextBlock>
<my:Map Width="445" x:Name="EventMap" Margin="0,0,0,20" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed">
<my:Map.CredentialsProvider>
<my:ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider ApplicationId="OMITED"></my:ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider>
</my:Map.CredentialsProvider>                                
</my:Map>                           
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this seems like more of a usage of `ScrollViewer`

```
<ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel>
 <my:Map> 
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

rather than ListBox. But anyway, I couldn't reproduce the problem. Does that button have some custom margins that could be doing that?

Here's the solution file I created to see the problem you have in the image. Note that I wasn't able to reproduce it in the solution.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip

Comment: That didn't fix it, I get that same effect if I use ScrollViewer or ListBox. The map still doesn't follow the boundary of the parent control. Your example was close, but with a few changes I could reproduce it. [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122492/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122492/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip)

Comment: I can't reproduce it with that example. Here's a picture http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/Capture.PNG

Comment: I posted an alternative way for you to achieve this. See if this works for you http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip

Comment: I've tried all these examples and change them slightly to reproduce the issue. Make a grid with 2 rows. The bottom grid has the button, the top grid holds a listbox with a map inside. Move the list box up and down, and you will see the map go out of bounds. I've tried it with grids, stackpanels, scrollviewers. Use the example I posted and move the listbox up and down near the text.[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122492/WindowsPhoneApplication1_v2.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122492/WindowsPhoneApplication1_v2.zip)